# How to select text over multiple non-text nodes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Context**

I have a website where users can write articles. After creating the article, other users should be able to go in and highlight any text within the article and make a comment on it (similar to the system on Medium). I do this by saving the user's highlight to a database and then checking the highlight against the article when it loads. However, the author of the article can bold and italicize text, which ruins the system because the `<strong>` and `<i>` tags get in the way. For example, if a user's article consisted of the following content:

```
<p>This is my article. <strong>Bolded text here.</strong></p>
```

and another user wanted to come in and highlight `my article. Bolded text`, that text would be saved to the database. Then, I insert the highlight into the article (which is just applying a `span` to the highlighted text) by using this code to replace the article's HTML with the highlight:

```
let $text = $("#articleContents");
let textCurrent = $text.html().trim();
let textToHighlight = text.trim();
let ifTextExists = textCurrent.indexOf(textToHighlight) > -1;

if (ifTextExists) {
    textCurrent = textCurrent.replace(textToHighlight, "<span class='highlights'>" + textToHighlight + "</span>");
    $text.html(textCurrent);
}
```

So, because I'm checking the article's HTML to see if a highlight matches, when the user wants to highlight the string `my article. Bolded text`, the content it is checked against is `article. <strong>Bolded text</strong>`, so the text is not highlighted (the class is not applied) because the tags get in the way. With Medium's system, any string can be highlighted regardless of whether it is bolded or not.

**Question**

How can I alter my code to disregard the non-text nodes and highlight the whole string, whether it's wrapped in tags or not?

**Things I Have Tried**

I have tried using `.text()` instead of `.html()`; the problem with that is that the HTML tags are removed from the article, which I need to be able to keep the structure of the article (for example, removing the `div` tags means
moving the text to a new line by pressing `enter` doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$text.text()` instead of `$text.html()` so it ignores tags.

Comment: I just edited the post to account for this, but I have already tried this. Any other ideas? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery for that. 
JavaScript solution: *`element.innerText`*

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.elementSelector')
elem.innerText;
```

JQuery solution: *`$(elem).text();`*

```
$('.elementSelector').text();
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the post, but I have tried that already. The problem is that, when the tags are removed, the new line doesn't work; so if the user presses enter, a DIV is inserted into the article. Removing it by using `.text()` would mean that it wouldn't work. Any other ideas? Sorry for failing to mention that.